# 2000 Toyota Celica GTS aftermarket exhaust system

Tags: toyota, exhaust, aftermarket-upgrade

I want to get a MagnaFlow Cat and Muffler. I need confirmation that the parts I've found online will indeed fit my Celica. I'm ignorant when it comes to cars (I filled the radiator coolant overflow container with the coolant stuff... twice) but I'm getting better, sort of. Luckily, I have the internet and a car mechanic friend.

Here are the two parts I found:

Catalytic Converter: [MagnaFlow Part #448610](http://www.magnaflow.com/02catalytic_converters/02product/displaydirectfit_obd.asp?directfit=448610)

Cat Back Muffler: [MagnaFlow Part #15812](http://www.magnaflow.com/02product/displayapplications.asp?partnumber=15812)

Also, will I need to buy anything extra (if these two fit) to make this work? I'm going to have a professional do the installation, so if there are any parts I need, now would be an excellent time to know.

Thanks!

Edit: The car was manufactured in Japan, so it does not have a California rating on the emission.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Where did the car come from? (ie: is it a California car), & 2) Which engine is in your Celica?

Comment: I don't think it came from Cali and I'm not in Cali. Not sure where it originated. & I believe it's the standard engine that comes in the GTS 6-Speed Manual, 4-Cyl 1.8L.

Comment: The pipes you are looking at are for California emissions, so I am not sure if it would be exactly the same. You can take your VIN to a Toyota dealer to make sure if it has Calif emissions. Then we can make an educated guess as to what exactly you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that as soon as I can and update the question.

Comment: @Paulster2 I updated the question with more information. It's not a Cali rated emission.

Comment: With all due respect, did you have the car (or VIN) *checked* on this? The reason I'm so specific is, a car can be *built* in Japan and still have Calif emissions. Even cars which are not sold in Calif can have Calif emissions. It's very important to know this for sure or you *may* end up with the wrong exhaust. I know I'm being nit-picky, but it is important. California is *stupid* about their emissions crap.

Comment: Yes, I had it checked. I also checked the label. It has federal on it. No mention of Cali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cat is the incorrect part for your vehicle. You are looking for the Federal ones, which are 49 state compliant.

Catalytic Converter: [MagnaFlow Part #24064](http://www.magnaflow.com/02catalytic_converters/02product/displaydirectfit01.asp?catalogid=46385&directfit=24064) (Fits GT, so you may want to check with MagnaFlow to ensure it will work with your engine ... check if your engine is a 1ZZFE motor.)

Cat Back Muffler: [MagnaFlow Part #15812](http://www.magnaflow.com/02product/shopexd.asp?zone=all&id=8581) is correct for your vehicle, though.

If you have any doubts and want to stick with the MagnaFlow line of exhaust systems, you can always call them. Like most major aftermarket brands, they have a tech line which will be more than happy to help you out: 1.800.824.8664 or via email: moreinfo@magnaflow.com

Comment: I checked and I have the 2ZZ-GE engine. The worst that can happen is that I have to send back a wrong fit cat and get a different one.